# I am changing the value of data-* attribute with the onclick function in jQuery. The value of the atribute changes but did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

My problem is in the following link,
http://www.cannonfoam.com/prdetail?id=212. This is a product page. where product have one primery image and two secondary images. the following link is provide detail and process to the liabrary that i have used for image zoom on hover. http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom. this liabrary use `src` attribute to show small image and then `data-zoom-image` attribute have the path of image that is to show as zoomed image..

Now, problem is that i have been asked that primary image should be replaced with a secondary image when clicked on a secondary image. I have created a function that replace `src` attribute value and `data-zoom-image` attribute value. image is changing successfully and when i inspect element then i can see that `data-zoom-image` attribute changes as well. but in zoomed image only primary image is visible..

i am unable to understad that when image path is changing in `data-zoom-image` attribute the why zoomed image is not beeing changed in zoom section..

please some body help me in this respact.. my client is geting angry on me.. waiting for correct solution..

Comment: there is a same example in your plugin website with your case. you just need to follow it

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image like this:

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>
```

Then you can activate the zoom functionality with this:

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
```

Comment: try to re-execute this `$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();` after you replace the image with the secondary image. Also, the secondary image should have a unique `id` so apply `$("#your-new-ID").elevateZoom();`

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the website.

Here is a hint.

```
var ez = $('#zoom_01').data('elevateZoom');
ez.swaptheimage('http://www.cannonfoam.com/assets/images/product/True Restb.jpg', 'http://www.cannonfoam.com/assets/images/product/True Restb.jpg');
```

my suggestion is that you should take a look and modify your click event.

Comment: here is the function.. i cant see any error in it.. tell if you see.<script type="text/javascript">
 
  $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
  
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   $(".thum").click(function(){
   
    var getsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    
    $("#zoom_01").attr("src", getsrc);
    $("#zoom_01").attr("data-zoom-image", getsrc);
   
   });
  
  });
  
 </script>

Comment: There is no error in your code. 
but you can try to use the snippet above add it in your click function.
see if the image is changed.
your job is to update the static img_path to the correct one.